# Coding a button on a form in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to build a database with MS Access. I have two tables- StockFrames and Projects, and I have a form- FrameCheckOut. On the form I have a FrameID field (where we will type in a frame id number or scan its barcode) and a ProjectName field, with a drop down of project names from the Projects table. I also have a button- Assign Frame. I want the button to update the StockFrames table with the projectID number so that I can know whether or not a frame is currently in use (or "checked out") to a project.

I have tried assigning this code to the button On Click:

```
UPDATE StockFrames 
SET StockFrames.projectID = [SELECT Projects.projectID 
FROM Projects WHERE Projects.projectName LIKE projectName]
WHERE frameID = frameID;
```

.. but that code contains invalid syntax. I am very new to Access and coding and I would really appreciate some help if anyone is willing.

Comment: Inner queries must be enclosed in parentheses, not brackets. I don't see why even using a nested query. Might explore MS LendingLibrary template database for ideas on how to check in/out items. Really should use ID fields for criteria instead of descriptive text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include key field in combobox (column can be hidden) RowSource. Value of combobox will be ID but users see and type name. Combobox properties:
RowSource: `SELECT ProjectID, ProjectName FROM Projects ORDER BY ProjectName;`
BoundColumn: 1
ColumnCount: 2
ColumnWidths: 0";2"
ControlSource: leave blank if control is used to enter search criteria, otherwise field you want to save into

If form is bound to StockFrames, an UPDATE action is not needed. Find record for specific FrameID and simply select project from combobox.

If you prefer to use UPDATE, then have UNBOUND comboboxes for Frames and Projects designed as described above. Example VBA:

```
Private Sub AssignFrame_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE StockFrames SET ProjectID = " & Me.cbxProject & _
      " WHERE FrameID = " & Me.cbxFrame
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I created a new form with combo boxes as you described above, but I'm still having some problems. When I enter a Frame ID and then attempt to select a project name from the drop down list, I get the error: "The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they created duplicate values in the index, primary key or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data....".  Thanks in advance for any advice you have on how to fix this.

Comment: Are these controls UNBOUND on UNBOUND form? Are you still trying to use UPDATE action?

Comment: I tried both ways. First I tried a form bound to StockFrames with two combo boxes- one for FrameID and then another combo box for Project name and ID with the properties set as suggested. I set the control source for the Project combo box to StockFrames.ProjectID because that is the field I wanted to save into. But when I tried to select from the Project Name drop down on form view, I couldn't select anything. Then I tried an unbound form as described with a button with the vba described above. In form view I am able to select fields, but it is not updating on the stock frames table.

Comment: Then I expect there is some other design issue and since I can't review db, can't advise.

Comment: I got it to work! Another question- I tried to add a "Clear" button to the same form with the wizard. But when I click it in form view I get the error "The command or action 'undo' isn't available now. Any idea how to fix that? Many thanks!

Comment: After selecting the frame id and the project from the drop down list, then clicking on the assign frame button, the information updates in the stock frames table as it should. But I want to have a button to clear the fields to get ready for the next frame and project assignment.

Comment: If this is an UNBOUND form then set each control equal to Null. If it is a BOUND form then move to new record row.