# Microsoft Access Query Results are Empty

Tags: ms-access

I don't understand why I'm getting empty results for my query (company name from Companies table and Shares Outstanding from Shares Outstanding table). Fields are linked (see below).

If I run the query using fields from one table only, I see results; just not when I'm pulling data from several tables.

See the below screenshots for the relationships, query setup and query results.

[image: Relationships]

[image: Query]

[image: Datasheet View]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those 3 Shares tables should be 1 table with another field for share type (outstanding, short, floating)

Companies table not linking to dependent tables on key fields. Companies table ID field is designated as primary key and should be saved as foreign key in number (long integer) field in dependent table. Just as was done with Sources and Exchanges tables.

Advise not to use exact same field name in multiple tables. Also, should not use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore is only exception) in naming convention.

Comment: Ok that did the trick. I don't want to memorize the company ID number every time I update the share info. Can I look up the company up by name instead of ID?

Comment: Read answer in this link and build combobox as described https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62092776/coding-a-button-on-a-form-in-ms-access/62094227#62094227